# fnv 0.2.0 Usage TypeError

Tags: python, fnv

I am trying to use fnv hash function on python-3.6, but I am getting an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/Users/SACHIN/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/bloom.py", line 4, in module
>       fnv.hash(data, algorithm=fnv.fnv_1a, bits=64)
>     File "C:\Users\SACHIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fnv__init__.py", line 52, in hash
>       OFFSET_BASIS[bits]
>     File "C:\Users\SACHIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fnv__init__.py", line 28, in fnv_1a
>       return ensure_bits_count((hash_value ^ byte) * PRIMES[bits], bits)
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'str'

For code

```
import fnv

data = 'my data'
fnv.hash(data, algorithm=fnv.fnv_1a, bits=64)
fnv.hash(data, bits=64)
fnv.hash(data, algorithm=fnv.fnv, bits=64)
```

which is exactly copied from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fnv/0.2.0

Please let me know what actually is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this error today. I got around it by encoding the string. For example, the below should all work.

```
import fnv

data = 'my data'
fnv.hash(data.encode(), algorithm=fnv.fnv_1a, bits=64)
fnv.hash(data.encode('ascii'), bits=64)
fnv.hash(data.encode('utf-8'), algorithm=fnv.fnv, bits=64)
```